# Simple Core Data fetch for to-many relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

Given that Dogs and Owners have a to-many relationship to each other, i.e.

```
(Owner)
@NSManaged public var dogs: NSSet?

(Dog)
@NSManaged public var owners: NSSet?
```

I have a DogProvider class that returns Dogs. It returns all Dogs by default. But in the case where I give the DogProvider an Owner, how do I return just the Dogs for that owner in an NSFetchedResultsController? I know the below doesn't work (`Cannot convert value of type 'Owner?' to expected argument type '[Any]?'`) but it's my latest attempt.

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Dog> = Dog.fetchRequest() //return all dogs by default
if let owner = self.owner {
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "owner = %@", argumentArray: self.owner)
}
```

Comment: You access the relationship as any other property, `owner.dogs` or `dog.owner` for instance

Comment: I understand that, but the view controller is expecting `dogProvider.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects`

Comment: If you have an Owner object then you don't need to perform a fetch, return owner.dogs if you have an owner object. `dogs` is a Set so you might need to do `Array(owner.dogs)` if you need to return an array like `fetchedObjects` does

Comment: `argumentArray` is an array. Try `argumentArray: [owner]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong API. `argumentArray` is for multiple placeholders where the number of items in the array must match the number of placeholders for example

```
let parameters = [foo, bar, baz]
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "foo = %@ AND bar = %@ AND baz = %@", argumentArray: parameters)
```

Just have to search for *`owners` contains `owner`* and it's a pretty bad idea to use `self.owner` as parameter after having safe unwrapped it

```
if let owner = self.owner {
   fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "owners CONTAINS %@", owner)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @willeke says in comments, the `argumentArray:` parameter requires an array.  But also your predicate needs to be slightly different because the relationship is many-many:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Dog> = Dog.fetchRequest() //return all dogs by default
if let owner = self.owner {
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY owner = %@", argumentArray: self.owner)
}
```

Note the "ANY " modifier.